# WebMethods: adding EventType Definition to EventTypeStore

Tags: jms, webmethods

I’m trying to enable JMS Adapter polling notifications, so that WebMethods flows could be triggered upon arrival of JMS messages.
However the notifications cannot be enabled as EventType Definitions are missing in EventTypeStore.

On the screenshot below a notification is set to enabled, but “Publish Events” cannot be turned on. Here’s the error I get:

[image]

What I’m trying to find out is how do I add this EventType Definition for an existing document?

Comment: This is the text of the error: [ART.116.3134] Adapter Runtime (Notification): Unable to Enable Publish Event for notification: DbPrismaICDomainJMSNotifRouter.TriggerAndNtf:ntfBusinessException
[ART.116.3139] Adapter Runtime (Notification): EventType Definition doesnt exists in the EventTypeStore for notification : DbPrismaICDomainJMSNotifRouter.TriggerAndNtf:ntfBusinessException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to check 'Publish events' for that. If you want to start execution of some Process instance for received JMS, just create a Start Message Event like this:

[image: start event example]

After that, create new Adapter Notification and set parameters like this:

[image: jms parameters example]

Process Engine subscription trigger should pick this message then and create new Process Instance for it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to poll for JMS messages?

I must say I'm not sure what your entire setup is.

For webMethods 8.2 and up

You can just create a JMS Trigger

[image]